# Is there a clear guideline on when should we use android:exported="true" and when should we use android:exported="false"?

Tags: android

To migrate to API 31, we need to specific either `android:exported="true"` or `android:exported="false"`.

However, the guideline isn't entire clear based on https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12

> If the app component includes the LAUNCHER category, set
> android:exported to true. In most other cases, set android:exported to
> false.

### android.intent.category.LAUNCHER

For activity which handles `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`, we need to use `android:exported="true"`

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:exported="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

---

So, if we are handling our own message like, we use `android:exported="false"`?

```
<receiver android:name="com.xxx.sticky.UnstickStickyBroadcastReceiver"
    android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.xxx.sticky.action.UNSTICK" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

---

What about if we are handling system message like

- android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE
- android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_DELETED
- android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED

Should we use `android:exported="false"` or `android:exported="true"`?

```
<receiver android:name="com.xxx.widget.MiniNoteAppWidgetProvider"
    android:label="@string/widget_mini_name"
    android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_DELETED" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
        android:resource="@xml/mini_note_widget_info" />
</receiver>

<receiver
    android:name="com.xxx.reminder.BootBroadcastReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

(As per testing so far, it seems that using `android:exported="false"` is fine.)

Is there any good guideline to explain the process of making such a decision?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a clear guideline on when should we use android:exported="true" and when should we use android:exported="false"?

If you are expecting third-party apps (or perhaps in a few places, system code) to interact with your components without a `PendingIntent`, the component needs to be exported. Otherwise, it does not.

When in doubt, do not export, and then test to confirm that your component works as expected.

> For activity which handles android.intent.category.LAUNCHER, we need to use android:exported="true"

Correct. That is because third-party apps (launchers, mostly) will need to start this activity, and they will not have a `PendingIntent` with which to do so.

> So, if we are handling our own message like, we use android:exported="false"?

If it is your own broadcast, hopefully you are using `PendingIntent` (e.g., for a `Notification` or app widget), in which case you would not need the `<intent-filter>` and the component does not need to be exported.

> What about if we are handling system message like...

The export rules for those are not generally documented, much to my dismay. Start with it being not exported, and only export them if you find that it is needed. Frankly, *why* system code can work with non-exported components has been a mystery to me.